# sending message through IP address in eclipse android program using sockets

Tags: java, android, eclipse, websocket, eclipselink

I want to make an app which could send message to a particular mobile phone which has the same application by using IP address of the receiver. Assume that we know the IP address of the receiver, there is no need to first find the IP address of the receiver. I just want to send message through IP address which i know. and one more thing i want to directly send message to  the receiver, there must be no 3rd party involved. i think we can use socket programming in this like we use in JAVA but i do not know how in android?? can anyone suggest me how to do it?? or can someone suggest  me some website where i can get coding part of this.

Comment: Then you want that we are creating that application for you..

Comment: No. NO. i just want to know the java part. i am not aware how to send data through IP address

Comment: yes I have the IP addesss

Comment: think about the `URL` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Smack API. You can [read here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application) for more information on how to use this API.

Comment: what if i do not want to use google talk??
In Java there is a concept of socket programming . can't we apply that in here/???

Comment: yes you can use websockets. http://jwebsocket.org/about-jws/Press-Articles/android/introduction-websockets-android

Comment: its fine but i want coding part.. do you know some website where i can get some tutorials or something related to it.??

Comment: You can start with something like this. http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/06/creating-a-jwebsocket-client-for-android-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to device using socket and once connected you can send a message to your service /application which is installed on device. This will in turn modify the DB of messaging. Once that gets modified, the message will displayed.